# How to shift the google map by changing the city from drop down?

Tags: google-maps

Pzz tell me the Code to shift the google map to a particular city when the city is selected from drop down list. i am doing this in eclipse with ibm worklight. plzzz help.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question but I shall try to provide an abstract solution to this one:

1. Use spinners in order to select a particular city. Follow the steps in this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) to figure out the code for the same.
2. Using the geocoder api pass the variable that holds the city name into the parameters that request for address so that you can get the specific Lat/Lng of that city. Fore code implementation have a look at this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/).
3. Finally the last step is to display the coordinates (Lat/Lng) on the map fragment. That is again a bunch of steps to be followed right from getting API key to displaying the Lat/Lng on maps. You can refer to above link that explains the same. To get API key follow this step by step [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) with images.

Hope this helps!!